# Web Development: Disabling Chrome's Cache doesn't work on osx

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, caching

For web development, I have disabled cache in Chrome -> Dev Tools -> Setting -> General -> Disable Cache.

However, when i refresh my site, it doesn't reflect my changes which is super annoying.
I have to manually empty the cache.

What is there that I might be doing wrong?

Note: I close my dev tools when i refresh as suggested here: [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Comment: I usually just `Ctrl+F5`, seems to handle most situations. Make sure your server isn't caching output too, as that can cause similar issues in development.

Comment: I am not on windows machine but i did try the equivalent command and it did not work and no my server  is not caching any output! :(

Comment: Ah, `command+shift+r`, `ctrl+shift+r` works in windows too, so if you work in both environments, switching to `ctrl/command+r` should be a decent workaround, using `shift` to cause it to also clear cache.

Comment: Just tried all the 3 possible solution, did not work :(. However, mozilla firefox seems to be working fine. It does pick up my changes. So, I am pretty sure it is not my code that is doing the hoodoo :P

Comment: Just figured out, I had breakpoints set up which wasn't letting cache clear out in order to maintain those breakpoints!! I will post this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the solution.

I **Disabled all the breakpoints** in my script and then reloaded, it takes up my latest changes.. Woohoooo :-)

Don't know why it does that but it fixed my problem. Perhaps, in order to maintain those breakpoints, it was not refreshing my js files.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in Google Chrome 43 64-bit on Windows 7. Yes, cache is marked as disabled. I have solved the problem by switching to Firefox.